# In the final method of batch class sending callout fails with SOQL Limit

Tags: soql, governorlimits, schedulebatch

I have a schedulable batch class which is stateful. In execute am inserting upto 1000 records.

In final method  i have a list of ids of inserted record

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
  {
                    if(Ids.size()>0)
                    {
                      for(string id : Ids)
                      {
                        // calling a static method sending id as paramter.
                      }
                    }
 
  }
```

In for loop for every id calling an static method with id as parameter.

The call static method will created an instance of another class which has nearly 10 queries and an http request.

am getting Too many SOQL queries: 201

This is my static method

```
global  class SClass
{
  
  public static void SMethod(String id)
  {      
                         
       
         Sclass2 s = new sclass2 (Id,false);
         s.test();// this method has http request and upto 10 soql queries
   }           
        
}
```

why do i get this even when we have created new instance for every id.

Any solution please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finish method runs don't have the asynchronous limits as the execute methods. Why don't you try and run your finish method logic in a different batch apex. You can call the batch apex from Queueable or in the finish method.

Comment: Am doing an callout in finish method. Since am doing an insert (dml), call out is not allowe after dml (correct me if am wrong) @mukul mahawariya

Comment: Thanks brining that into my attention, I have updated the answer.

Comment: So need to create another batch class with list of ids( 1000 and more ids) which will execute the below. 
in for loop in execute method.`
Sclass2 s = new sclass2 (Id,false);
s.test();// this method has http request and upto 10 soql queries
`
 does the batch class execute will not have the governor limitations ?

Comment: So need to create another batch class with list of ids( 1000 and more ids) which will execute the below. 
in for loop in execute method.

`
Sclass2 s = new sclass2 (Id,false);
s.test();// this method has http request and upto 10 soql queries`

 does the batch class execute will not have the governor limitations ?

Comment: Start, execute, and finish methods can implement up to 100 callouts each. You only need to iterate over the in a chunk of 100.
SOQL limit is 200 in asynchronous apex.

Comment: So we need to create new batch class instance for every 100 ids?

Comment: No, You just pass all the ids to the batch and execute it in a chunks of 100

Comment: I will pass all 1000  ids to the another batch. I dont have anything to query in  start. then how can i execute it in a chunck of 100s

i just have to do this in execute which doesn't have  anything to query.

Sclass2 s = new sclass2 (Id,false);
s.test();// this method has http request and upto 10 soql queries

Comment: Why don't you again query on the 1000 IDs?

Comment: How can we do that? In start method  we can do only one query and based that the execute will be processed ryt?

Comment: You can create a different constructor for batch class and pass the Ids as a parameter. Follow this example - 

https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/06/passing-parameter-to-batch-apex-in.html

Comment: I have passed the paramters. how to do query on 1000 ids

Comment: you need to add where condition in the query . Ex - [SELECT Id FROM Object WHERE Id IN: IDS]

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.

Comment: Thanks  Mukul. It worked for me.